# Classic ASP debug not working when a file is included

Tags: asp-classic

in my include folder I have the file SqlOperations.asp

```
<% 
    Option Explicit

    Function CheckSqlConnection()
        Dim sqlConnection, connString 
        connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False; uid=sa; pwd=123456789;Initial Catalog=UserDatabase;Data Source=lakpa-pc"
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        SET sqlConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        sqlConnection.Open connString

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            CheckSqlConnection = false
        End If

        CheckSqlConnection = sqlConnection
        On Error Goto 0
    End Function

    Function ExecuteNonQuery(sqlQuery)
        Dim checkSql, sqlCmd
        checkSql = CheckSqlConnection
        If checkSql == False Then
            Response.Write("Please check your connection string <br/>" & vbCrlf)
            Response.End
            ExecutenonQuery = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        checkSql.Execute(sqlQuery) 
        ExecuteNonQuery = True
    End Function

 %>
```

then when I call it from UserInformation.asp which is in root folder

```
<!--#include file="include/SqlOperations.asp" -->
<%
    OPTION EXPLICIT

    dim fName, mName, lName,age,address,postCode,telephone, queryVal
    fName = Request.Form("fName")
    mName = Request.Form("mName")
    lName = Request.Form("lName")
    age = Request.Form("age")
    address= Request.Form("address")
    postCode = Request.Form("postCode")
    telephone = Request.Form("telephone")
    if fName <>"" then
        queryVal = "INSERT INTO UserInfo(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, age, Address, PostCode, Telephone) VALUES('" + fName +"','" + mName+"','" + lName+"','" + age +"','" + address +"','" + postCode +"','" + telephone +"')"
        ExecuteNonQuery queryVal

    end if


 %>
```

The Debug isn't working. But If I remove the include line then the debug works and I get the error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'ExecuteNonQuery
```

I just don't understand it. I am new to ASP classic. Can any one tell me the reason why its happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was the syntax, I was confused. I used "If checkSql == False Then", the syntax was wrong it should have only one "=" sign. Well I modified little bit of it and now its working fine. This is for connecting ASP Classic with MSSQL. May be it will be helpful to somebody. 
Thanks Kane for the reply :)

```
  Function CheckSqlConnection()
    Dim sqlConnection, connString 
    connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False; uid=sa; pwd=123456789;Initial Catalog=UserDatabase;Data Source=lakpa-pc"
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    SET sqlConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    sqlConnection.Open connString

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        CheckSqlConnection = false
    End If

    set CheckSqlConnection = sqlConnection
    On Error Goto 0
End Function

Function ExecuteNonQuery(sqlQuery)
    Dim checkSql
    set  checkSql = CheckSqlConnection
    If checkSql = False Then
        Response.Write("Please check your connection string <br/>" & vbCrlf)
        Response.End
        ExecutenonQuery = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    checkSql.Execute(sqlQuery) 
    ExecuteNonQuery = True
End Function

Sub SqlConnectionClose(SqlConn)
    SqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For functions is ASP classic you need to use brackets, E.G.,

```
ExecuteNonQuery(queryVal)
```

Should fix your problem.

Comment: I already tried that but its not working. The debug isn't getting called nor I get errors.
Removing the include file gives problem and including it nothing works.